# Allow only few devices to access data in firebase on custom rules

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a android Kiosk application. We install the app manually on to the devices. The data is fetched from the Firebase. I would like to set up rules in Firebase so that only the devices having my app installed should be able to access the data.

Each device have a deviceId generated like below

```
String thisDeviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(MyApplication.getAppContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

and each device is given a group Id when registering the device.

All the data present falls under these two categories

1. devices/deviceId/path
2. groups/groupId/path

I want to set the below rules in firestore:
A device with a deviceId "abc" can only access the path(read and write) devices/abc/path
A devicve with group "cde" can only access the path (read and write) groups/cde/path

I tried reading the documentation but I am not able to understand any that suits my requirements. Any idea how this can be achieved? Any thoughts will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Firestore security rules don't support the idea of using some device ID to limit access.  This ID could be easily spoofed by malicious clients.  The only possible way to limit access is per-user with Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your  inputs. Does taht mean all the devices where the app is installed should have a google account? Also, Our app has a offline mode which works with out internet. The data is fetched once a day on to the device from firebase and then the data is cached when there is no interner connection. Can the firebase authentication work without internet connection?

Comment: I changed my mobile so that the authentication will be done by google provider in Firebase. I am facing some other problem when adding rules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870178/request-auth-token-email-not-present-in-the-rules  Can you please have a look and see you have any idea? Thanks