# request.auth.token.email not present in the rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Our app uses Firebase as the back end database. Firebase provides authentication for our app with google as the only provider. The authentication works fine. I am getting a "SUCCESS" in the authentication result. I would like to change my firebase rules so only the users that are present in a collection can access the data. For it, I have the rules in firebase to control access to the data. The rules are not working when I use any variables from request.auth.(where as the same works from a simulator)

Below rule working in both app and simulator:

```
match /restaurants/{$rId}/addresses/{document=**} {
    allow read, write : if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/abc@gmail.com).data.restaurantId == $rId;
}
```

Below rule NOT working from app but working in simulator

```
match /restaurants/{$rId}/addresses/{document=**} {
    allow read, write : if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.token.email)).data.restaurantId == $rId;
}
```

I am sending the authentication request from the app as follows:

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Handling the authentication result below:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
             Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         }
    }
}
```

My firebase database contains the following structures

Users:

```
/users
   abc@gmail.com
            -restaurantId: "1"
```

Restaurants:

```
/restaurants
   1
          addresses
                 local
                     -name: a
                 international
                     -name: b 

   2
          addresses
                 local
                     -name: c
                 international
                     -name: d 
   3
          addresses
                 local
                     -name: e
                 international
                     -name: f
```

I am able to see the Toast "Login successful" when the user tries to login with a valid password.

Should I save the authentication result in the onActivityResult so that further requests will have the request.auth.token.email present? Kinldy please guide me. 
Can anyone please let me know if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: There is no need to store the token in code yourself. The Firebase client takes care of that for you. Can you show the code of where you read/write the database?